# How to set MessageBoxW parameter to disable the Close [x] Button on Message Box using ctypes Python?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, message, box

I have a custom script in Python that creates a message on Windows OS system, I would like to know if it is possible to disable the Close [x] Button on the box message layout..

Here it is my code:

```
message= itsm.getParameter('get_message')
title= itsm.getParameter('get_title')
import os
import ctypes

uTypeNbutton = 0x40 #configure the button and uType style
def Mbox(title, text, style):
style=int(uTypeNbutton)+4096 #to make message box top all windows
return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text,title, style)
```

Pls check this image to understand what I want to disable
[image]

Comment: There is no style for a [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) that removes the close button.

Comment: I don't want to remove it, I just want to disable it, when the user clicks on it, he can't not close or exit the message... I was able to do that using the |YES |NO layout but, for some reason it won't work with the |OK| Layout, if you know I what mean|

Comment: What's the rationale behind harassing the user to click a specific button rather than closing the dialog using the close button? And what are you going to do about them offenders that are just going to press the Escape key? It's not impossible to disable the close button. The fact that the API doesn't provide an interface for it should make you question your design.

Comment: Its in my client's requirements to do this message layout, and behave, so I don't question, as I said before, I was able to do it using the option YES| NO... and it works fine.

Comment: `MB_YESNO` is different. It expects an answer. `MB_OK` doesn't expect an answer. Forcing a user to dismiss a dialog a certain way when the program doesn't care about how the user dismissed the dialog is called harassment.

Comment: Understood, maybe that's the reason...

Comment: Is there a return value when the user clicks on the close[x] option? I will traceback the user's reaction to the dialog... this is a better way to handle this... I see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox the return value for OK is 1 but, can't find the return value for the close[x] action.

Comment: Do you know how to do what you want in C? If not, then the `python` and `ctypes` tags are pure noise.

Comment: I realize it... btw the message dialog return always a int 1 regardless of whether the user clicks on Ok or close the the dialog... pretty annoying... I can't traceback the user's behavior unfortunately